# How do I get replaceRoot to return an object instead of an array?

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, lookup, aggregation

I have 2 collections, `ratePlans` and `properties`.

Properties has an array of `cancelPolicies` as a subdocument and `ratePlans` has `cancelPolicyId` to reference this.

I am trying to lookup the cancellation policy for a given `ratePlan`.

```json
$lookup: {
  from: "properties",
  let: { propertyId: "$propertyId", cancelPolicyId: "$cancelPolicyId" },
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$propertyId" ] } }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$cancelPolicies",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },
    { 
      $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$cancelPolicies._id", "$$cancelPolicyId" ] } }
    },
    // I tried this, but it does nothing. I also tried putting it after replaceRoot:
    // {
    //   $unwind: {
    //     path: "$cancelPolicies",
    //     preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    //   }
    // },
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$cancelPolicies" }
    },
  ],
  as: "cancelPolicy"
}
```

This works, however `cancelPolicy` is now an array of length 1 instead of an object. Is it possible to have `cancelPolicy` be the actual object instead of an array?

Comment: Do an $unwind of $cancelPolicy after the $lookup (so as the second stage to the overall pipeline rather than being nested inside of the $lookup)

Comment: @user20042973 Oh why didn't I think of that. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have to do with `$replaceRoot` directly. In the question it's noted that the field with an unexpected type is `cancelPolicy`. The `cancelPolicy` field, not to be confused with `cancelPolicies` or `cancelPolicyId`, contains the result of the `$lookup`. That is to say that `cancelPolicy` is the `as` parameter of the `$lookup` which is defined as follows in [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (emphasis added):

> Specifies the name of the new **array field** to add to the input documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from the from collection. If the specified name already exists in the input document, the existing field is overwritten.

There is nothing that you can do *inside* of the `$lookup`, including in its nested `pipeline`, to coerce the type into anything other than an array.

The solution is to modify that field in these new documents in a subsequent stage. Most commonly this is achieved with an `$unwind` stage. So the aggregation would look something like this:

```
$lookup: {
  from: "properties",
  let: { propertyId: "$propertyId", cancelPolicyId: "$cancelPolicyId" },
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$propertyId" ] } }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$cancelPolicies",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },
    { 
      $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$cancelPolicies._id", "$$cancelPolicyId" ] } }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$cancelPolicies" }
    },
  ],
  as: "cancelPolicy"
},
{
  $unwind: "$cancelPolicy"
}
]
```

You can include the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` parameter in there as well depending on whether you are looking to perform a logical inner join or a left join.